# Как сделать так, чтобs код дальше не шел до получения ответа от функции

Tags: python, telegram, бот

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.row("English ", "Український ", "Беларускі ")
    markup.row("Français ", "Deutsch ", " عرب")
    markup.row("More")
    message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           "Choose the language in which the bot will communicate:", 
reply_markup=markup)
**bot.register_next_step_handler(message, start_next)**

global properties
global weather_parameters
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
markup.row("Let's go!", "Info")
markup.row("Settings")
message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           "*I'm Weather_Bot*\nYou can get the weather and moon phase "
                           "coordinats!\nTo start click *Let's Go!*\nFor FAQ click *Info*\n"
                           "For changing views options click *Settings*", reply_markup=markup,
                           parse_mode="Markdown")
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, language)
```

надо чтобы сработала функция start_next и только после этого код шел дальше
код функции start_next:

```
def start_next(message):
if message.text[:-3] in langs.keys():
    active_lang = langs[message.text[:-3]]
    global request_headers
    request_headers = {"Accept-Language": active_lang}
elif message.text == "More":
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.row("বাংলা ", "català ", "Русский ")
    markup.row("Afrikaans ", "हिंदी ", "አማርኛ ")
    markup.row("Ελληνικά ", "eesti keel ", "Farsi ")
    markup.row("galego ", "Magyar ", "bahasa Indonesia ")
    markup.row("Italiano ", "lietuvių ", "Malagasy " )
    markup.row("norsk ", "Nederlands ", "Occitan ")
    markup.row("Português ", "Română ", "Tamil ")
    markup.row("Türk ", "Tswana ", "Tiếng Việt ")
    message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                               "Choose the language in which the bot will communicate:", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, start_next)
```

Comment: Ну так и поместите этот код в функцию `start_next`

Comment: А где код функции `start_next`? В вопросе требуется [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve).

Comment: прикрепил код функции

Comment: ну так помести этот код после вызова функции. Код выполняется в том порядке, в котором написан